# Подключение к аккаунту Telegram через JAVA API (не через бота!)

Tags: java, api, telegram

Пытаюсь написать простенький Java-клиент, который будет подключаться к личному Телеграм аккаунту, считывать и обрабатывать нужные мне сообщения. Задача вроде бы простая, но в гугле гайды только по ботам( 
На официальной странице есть описания апи методов и способ получения App configuration (api_id, api, hash, имя клиента и т.д.), нашел библиотеку, подключил через мавен. Но изучения библиотеки тоже особых результатов не принесло.
Подскажите пожалуйста, через какие классы и каким образом можно решить мою задачу?